# nesting of table tag inside table tag

Tags: html

Is it ok to use table tag inside a table tag as shown below,
Is it syntactically correct?

Html:

```
 <table width="100%">
   <table width="100%">
          <tr>
             <td> Lorem Ipsum </td>
          </tr>                 
   </table>     
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

No It is not syntactically correct, You need to add `table` in `td`

```html
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
               <table width="100%">
                   <tr>
                      <td> Lorem Ipsum </td>
                   </tr>      
              </table>     
        </td>
     </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: yeah, I am aware of this. What if we do like that? hope it doesn't cause any real time issues if we start table after table.

Comment: I think, it's not affect in static html but when you used in dynamic table or with dynamic code then it will affect

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                  <td>   Lorem Ipsum (Add table inside td)             
                  </td>
               </tr>      
          </table>      
    </td>
 </tr>   
</table>
```